# Android page not showing in ICS properly

Tags: android

I have a main screen. In all mobiles with different screen sizes I checked its showing properly. But in ICS that is in Android 4.0.3, it's not showing in full screen. When I start, for 1 second it's showing and then going leaving back a white patch. Can anyone tell me whats the problem here? I think problem is in my main.xml. But I am not getting anything......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E1E1E1" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="508dp"
        android:paddingTop="94dp" >

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="459dp"
            android:background="#E1E1E1"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView android:contentDescription="@drawable/logolive1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/logolive1" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAuctions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="@string/btnAuctions" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="@string/btnSearch" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnUserProfile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="@string/btnUserProfile" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFeatAuct"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="@string/btnFeatAuct" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFeatItems"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="@string/btnFeatItems" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="@string/btnLogin" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:paddingTop="24dp"
                    android:text="@string/search_label"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:ems="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>


                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/group1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/option1"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:text="@string/live"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/option2"
                            android:checked="false"
                            android:text="@string/archive"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dummy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="99dp" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSearchLive"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/btnSearchLive" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/tab4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/tab5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wv1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/client"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lotno"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lottitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView android:contentDescription="@+id/lotimage"
                    android:id="@+id/lotimage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/highbid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lotopened"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/loginwindow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="@string/username_label"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <EditText 
                    android:id="@+id/uname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:ems="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="@string/pword_label"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/pword"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:autoText="true"
                    android:ems="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btndoLogin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/btndoLogin" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Any Help regarding this question??????????

Comment: the xml that u have given is fine i cannot make out any difference.... unless u donn give the java code where u have used this xml how can one find the real mistake behind the white patch.. bcoz i guess ur webview takes all the space thats marked with the white patch.So it would be good if u upload the java code

Comment: Ur Webview is taking the View of the Framelayout.

Comment: yes @ErrorHandler i got that the problem is with webView...But how to solve that..please help.....

Comment: Actually I cant remove that webview also..as in my java file every file m using that and i need that also...so any solution please

Comment: Can u tell me its working?then only can i give u the solution

Comment: No its not working...same white patch is coming.....please give the solution

Comment: Where do u want to show the webview ???or hw much area shld the web view cover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ff0000"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="508dp"
        android:paddingTop="94dp" 
        >

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="459dp"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAuctions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="xc" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="nm" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnUserProfile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="yu" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFeatAuct"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="ghj" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFeatItems"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="hd" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="t" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:paddingTop="24dp"
                    android:text="r"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:ems="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>


                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/group1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/option1"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:text="re"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/option2"
                            android:checked="false"
                            android:text="we"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dummy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="99dp" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSearchLive"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="we" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/client"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lotno"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lottitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView android:contentDescription="@+id/lotimage"
                    android:id="@+id/lotimage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/highbid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lotopened"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/loginwindow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="as"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <EditText 
                    android:id="@+id/uname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:ems="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="ca"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/pword"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:autoText="true"
                    android:ems="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btndoLogin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="as" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <SlidingDrawer
                    android:id="@+id/drawer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:content="@+id/content"
                    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/handle"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:background="#777777"
                        android:text="Hold"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:visibility="gone" >
                    </TextView>

                      <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#123123"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/tab4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/tab5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wv1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
           </SlidingDrawer>
    </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

just add the sliding drawer inside the framelayout and in the java code just add the webview inside the sliding drawer its the perfect solution .

Just add this in Java.

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;

```
public class New extends Activity {

    private SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.test);
slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
slidingDrawer.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: it depends its better to use only one webview.inside the sliding drawer and mark the answer right if it was useful

Comment: sure...but its saying that   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- SlidingDrawer (Change to android.widget.SlidingDrawer, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Comment: The handle attribute is must refer to an existing child. I am getting this error also..are u in any chat room

Comment: I am using android 1.0 @Error Handler

Comment: its wrking fine with android 4.1

Comment: are u using views.. can u plz post ur java code. i guess something is wrong with ur java code now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19204/discussion-between-suchi-and-error-handler)

Comment: can u come to this room Discussion between Suchi and Error Handler

Comment: but 1 problem..other webviews are not showing.for that I have to click the hold ..which I dont want

Comment: i guess then u need to create a totally different layout after ur tablelayout which takes the area after ur rows get created.

Comment: since u are using framelayout and inside that u are using tablelayout

Comment: so the tablelayout take the area of provided by the frame layout.And when u use a webview in between it also tries to take the area of the whole framelayout which leads to a conflict in the view

Comment: then what is the solution....1 thing what code u have given na in that if i am clicking the hold then the webpage are coming....which i want to come directly on change of tab .now after changing the tab i have to click the Hold to see the page...is there solution for that

Comment: to avoid that conflict we were using sliding drawer.nw what u can do is add a totally diff layout and add all the view inside it but ur scroll will be to big. try to optimize it just lemme knw whatz the use of three webviews are u using the in one activity itself. i suggest u to use one webview and use them wherver needed

Comment: yes u can add animate open for the sliding drawer when click of the tab

Comment: I am using one activity class..Can u tell me how to add animate open for the sliding drawer when click of the tab